# Generate custom output on URL with directory in WordPress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm trying to create a custom URL where I will output some string. The problem is that I want this URL to include a `/.well-known/` directory and when I do this, 403 forbidden error occures. So my current code works without directory and not works with `/.well-known/` directory. Here is my code:

```
add_action('parse_request', 'custom_output');
function custom_output() {            
    global $wp;
    global $wp_query;
    $urlEnd = 'custom-output'; // This will work
    $desiredUrlEnd = '.well-known/custom-output'; // This will not work
    
    if (!$wp_query->is_main_query()) {
        return;
    }

    if ($wp->request === $desiredUrlEnd) {
        $wp_query->set($desiredUrlEnd, 1);
    }

    if ($wp_query->get($desiredUrlEnd)) {
        @ini_set('display_errors', 0);
        @header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
        @header('X-Robots-Tag: noindex, follow');

        echo 'custom output';
        exit;
    }
}
```

So it works with `$urlEnd` and output shows on `https://example.com/custom-output` but it doesn't works with `$desiredUrlEnd` and it results in error when I access `https://example.com/.well-known/custom-output`. How can I make it work?

Thanks!